# sphinx-apidoc does not find all python files

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have the following two classes:

```
class Test1():
    """Test1()"""

    def fn_test1():
        """fn_test1 """
        print "Hello1"
```

.

```
class Test2():
    """Test2()"""

    def fn_test2():
        """fn_test2 """
        print "Hello2"
```

These classes are stored in different folders which is shown below:

```
$ tree -A
.
├── docs
│   ├── _build
│   ├── conf.py
│   ├── index.rst
│   ├── make.bat
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── _static
│   ├── _templates
│   └── Test1.rst
└── src
    └── standard
        ├── test1
        │   └── Test1.py
        └── test2
            └── Test2.py
```

I tried to run sphinx-apidoc, but it only finds Test1.rst with the following command:

```
$ sphinx-apidoc -f -A "Author" -H "Test project" -V "version 1.0" -R "release 2014" -F -d 4 -e -P -o docs /home/u/tmp/sphinx/src/standard/*
Creating file docs/Test1.rst.
Creating file docs/conf.py.
Creating file docs/index.rst.
Creating file docs/Makefile.
Creating file docs/make.bat.
```

If I remove * it finds nothing:

```
$ sphinx-apidoc -f -A "Author" -H "Test project" -V "version 1.0" -R "release 2014" -F -d 4 -e -P -o docs /home/u/tmp/sphinx/src/standard/
Creating file docs/conf.py. 
Creating file docs/index.rst.
Creating file docs/Makefile.
Creating file docs/make.bat.
```

How is it possible to call sphinx-apidoc that it finds Test1.py and Test2.py?

Answer (score 1):

Python packaging depends on directories tree. So from what you've done, *standard* is a package with two "subpackages", *test1* and *test2*. Each subpackage contains a module, either *Test1* or *Test2*.

You must add an (possibly) empty file called **__init__.py** to each directory containing a package and run

```
sphinx-apidoc -f -A "Author" -H "Test project" -V "version 1.0" -R "release 2014" -F -d 4 -e -P -o docs /home/u/tmp/sphinx/src/standard/
```

without the * sign.

Comment: I added "\_\_init\_\_.py" and sphinx-apidoc created standard.rst, standard.test1.Test1.rst, standard.test1.rst, standard.test2.Test2.rst, standard.test2.rst.

However, make html complains about No module named Test1, No module named standard, No module named standard.test1, No module named standard.test1.Test1, No module named standard.test2, No module named standard.test2.Test2, /home/mictadlo/tmp/sphinx/docs/Test1.rst:: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree

Comment: Of course, you get a .rst file per package and module, hence 3 packages and 2 modules in your case. The Test1.rst file was generated by a *previous* call to sphinx-apidoc. To start on a clean basis, empty your docs directory.

The make complain is a fully different problem. That is because your src directory is not included in your path.

Comment: I think it has worked out, but why is "module contents" empty [in the documentation](http://i.imgur.com/oUPvkGL.png?1) and are there any examples how to modify "\_\_init\_\_.py" to make nicer headings e.g. to change "standard package" to "Test project" and to change "Subpackages" to "standard package"?

Comment: I don't understand this behaviour of apidoc either. But I can say that **__init__.py** is not meant for documentation output, but to control package import behaviour.